# Output css file only compiles if it's empty first. Have to delete css contents, save css, then trigger watch on scss

Tags: npm, sass, compilation

I have the following package.json however on my environment (windows 10/vs code/vagrant homestead php) compile:development only works if I empty my outputted build.css first, then hit save and trigger the watch.  Otherwise the css file never changes.  This apparently works on somebody else machine (could be a red herring; trust no-one).

```
"scripts": {
    "autoprefixer": "postcss -u autoprefixer --no-map -r assets/css/*.css",
    "compile:production": "node-sass --omitSourceMapUrl true --output-style compressed -o assets/css assets/scss",
    "compile:development": "node-sass --omitSourceMapUrl true --output-style expanded -o assets/css assets/scss",
    "watch:css": "onchange \"assets/scss\" -- run-s development:css",
    "watch:js": "run-s development:js",
    "development:css": "run-p compile:development autoprefixer",
    "development:js": "rollup -c -w",
    "production:css": "run-p compile:production autoprefixer",
    "production:js": "rollup -c --compact",
    "build": "run-p production:*",
    "serve": "run-p watch:*"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.2.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^17.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.6",
    "core-js": "^3.8.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^2.1.1",
    "onchange": "^5.2.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "rollup": "^2.34.1",
    "rollup-plugin-gzip": "^2.5.0",
    "rollup-plugin-multi-input": "^1.1.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills": "^0.2.1",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^6.0.4",
    "uikit": "^3.6.16"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrote the compile scripts as the below to get it to work

```
    "compile:production": "node-sass --omitSourceMapUrl true --output-style compressed assets/scss -o assets/css",
    "compile:development": "node-sass -w assets/scss -o assets/css",
```